# Compiling with scalac does not find sbt dependencies

Tags: scala, sbt, scalac

I tried running my Scala code in VSCode editor. I am able to run my script via `spark-submit` command. But when I am trying with `scalac` to compile, I am getting:

> .\src\main\scala\sample.scala:1: error: object apache is not a member of package org
> import org.apache.spark.sql.{SQLContext,SparkSession}

I have already added respective library dependencies to *build.sbt*.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried running `sbt compile`?

Running `scalac` directly means you're compiling only one file, without the benefits of sbt and especially the dependencies that you have added in your *build.sbt* file.

In a sbt project, there's no reason to use `scalac` directly. This defeats the purpose of sbt.